# Excesive instances of citing or making reference to something

Tags: single-word-requests, repetition

What is the word for the act of repetitively making ad nauseam reference to something, or citing it to the point that either it annoys or it becomes trite?

Comment: Academic research

Comment: [Regurgitate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regurgitate) implies they do not know what they are saying, [restate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restate) or [reiterate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reiterate) may also fit, as in 'reiterated excessively'.

Comment: Comments can’t be downvoted, so I’ll comment that the non-joke suggestions above don’t really add anything. _Cited excessively_ would be more clear, if that’s what OP wants to say. _Regurgitate, restate,_ and _reiterate_ themselves just mean to repeat something (once). There’s no sense of reference, citation, or resultant triteness in any of them.

Answer (score 1):

One way I have heard people communicate this sort of thing is by saying that the thing is really **in the back pocket** of the person making the repeated reference. I can’t find a non-anecdotal source for this, so take it with a grain of salt. Also, note that the same term is used to connote influence bordering on control of one person over another, such as, “Tread lightly, she has a powerful politician in her back pocket.”

Another way you could consider saying it is that they really have that reference **on speed dial.** This is a reference to a more or less obsolescent phone feature that would allow the device’s owner to program telephone numbers to dedicated buttons on the phone, allowing the person to place a call to one such number with a single keypress. The term is used for similar features in smartphones and in other places as well, so it’s definitely still in the language. It implies that the person makes reference to (or *calls)* something often enough to warrant use of a dedicated button or slot.

You could also call someone a **[broken record](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sound+like+a+broken+record).** This just means they repeat something a lot, not that they *refer to* or *cite* something necessarily.

Something else I’ve heard is to reduce the person’s identity to the act of making the specific reference, such as:

> *I dunno, but Simpsons references are a great way to gain my respect.*
>
> *Hmm... you must worship me, then. I am **a walking Simpsons reference.***
> <sub>Source: [boards.straightdope.com](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-25563.html)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Something that is overused to the point where it becomes annoying is clichéd.